# combine all result in jQuery .each()

Tags: jquery

I use a function to get the text of clicked badge. Now I want to combine all results:

**For example:**

Badge 1 has class active and text = 'test1'
Badge 2 has class active and text = 'test2'

**Output:**

*Components test1 test2*

Currently, they are not be combined.

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.badgeFilter',
  function(){
        $( ".badgeFilter.active" ).each(function( index) {
          activeFilter = $( this ).text();  
    });
$('.compTitle').html('<i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Components ' + activeFilter );
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**map**](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [**join**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
$(document).on('click', '.badgeFilter',
  function(){
    var activeFilter = $( ".badgeFilter.active" ).map( function() {
          return $(this).text();  
    }).get().join(' ');
$('.compTitle').html('<i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Components ' + activeFilter );
});
```

Comment: Great AmmarCSE, that rocks! Thank you for your help